# PCb creation: how far to keep 240v ac from low voltage?

Tags: pcb

as the title describes, I have a question about the distance that should be kept between low voltage and high voltage PCB traces. Does anyone know the standarts for Europe?

Comment: Start from CE. Distance should be taken from standard, not from a forum.

Comment: If it was that simple. It depends on base material, coating, humidity, even trace width and bends. And if you want to achieve FELV, PELV or SELV. The standard is EN 60664-1. Rule of thumb: 2mm for FELV and PELV, 4mm for SELV against 250VAC. Double insulation required for PELV and SELV.

Comment: Put a leakage-collection trace between the HV and LV, if the LV is a signal.

Comment: What is the application? The standards vary a lot depending on the use of the product and the environment it used in.  Then buy a copy of the standard or employ an expert.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the IEC 60950 standard is what you are looking for.  I haven't studied it in detail, however if you follow the IPC guidelines they are slightly stricter and err on the side of safety.  For 240V I would recommend a spacing of at least 2.5mm, for safety reasons.

Comment: I don't work on a lot of things that are driven by Europe's requirements, so I'm sure there are other standards I am unaware of.

Comment: 2.5mm spacing between 240V and low voltage seems quite small to me.

Comment: As an idea - take any computer equipment power supply of good quality, open and and examine how its PCB is designed. I am sure you can find photos on the internet too. Spacing, (separate) grounding, etc etc - learn from things already out there

Comment: @Chupacabras 2.5mm is the IPC guideline for exposed conductors at 300-500V.